# Event change on struts2 optiontransferselect tag

Tags: javascript, struts2, dom-events

Can someone tell me if there is way to enable sort option for `optiontransferselect`? When items are moved from one list to another, the following script is called on the arrow buttons

```
<input type="button"
 value="&lt;-" onclick="moveSelectedOptions(document.getElementById('myForm_deliverableIPObject_selectedLibGroups'), document.getElementById('libGroup'), false, '');" /><br /><br />
```

The third argument here is supposed to be true if the auto sort should be enabled. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the only option is to change FreeMarker template for `optiontransferselect`. Copy `optiontransferselect.ftl` from simple theme to your project and change this parameter to true.

Comment: Hi Aleksandr, Can you please give me more details on where this file is located? i checked freemarker-2.3.16.jar that Im using but I couldn't find it here.

Comment: It is in struts2-core jar template/simple.